# Function or loop for checkboxes

Tags: c#, checkbox

So I have for example 5 checkboxes named checkbox1, checkbox2 etc.

All of them have assigned parameter in other function ( checkbox1 has string text1 = "t1", checkbox2 string text2 = "t2" etc). Those strings can be random, but only gives true when they are as above.

Lets make that user select 3 checkboxes, click some button and....

How to make function/loop that check only those selected checkboxes and see if checkbox1 has text1 = t1 etc ?
Something like this:

```
string text1, text2, text3, text4, text5 = null;
int a = 0;

while (a != 347)
{
    text1 = SomeOperation1();
    text2 = SomeOperation2();
    text3 = SomeOperation3();
    text4 = SomeOperation4();
    text5 = SomeOperation5();

    if ((checkbox1.Checked && text1 == "t1") && 
        (checkbox3.Checked && text3 == "t3") && 
        (checkbox5.Checked && text5 == "t5"))
    {
        SomeOperation6();
        a = 347;
    }
}
```

This `if` is wrong, couse it must select checked boxes (user can select  more or less than 3), but now maybe u understand what i want :)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: What do you mean by "checkbox1 has string text1 = t1"? That does not make sense. Do you mean `checkbox1.Text = "t1";`? It might be helpful if you showed some code, or described more specifically what you want to do (i.e. use a real-world example).

Comment: Don't write code by hand.  Copy and paste.  Your posted code won't compile.  And don't make it wordier than it needs to be.  Don't write `if (checkBox1.Checked == true)`, it should just be `if (checkBox1.Checked)`  Post code that duplicates the problem.  "some operation" leaves a lot of holes.

Comment: Well the point is that i dont have "copy and paste" code. Wrote it to gives you idea what i want to get. Dont compile it. The IF is what I want to get but how to make it correct ?

Answer (score 1):

All the controls on a Form can be found in the form's `Controls` collection (note that controls that are part of a container control will be found in that container control's `Controls` collection).

You can use the `System.Linq` extension method `OfType` to get only the controls that are of a specific type, by doing something like this:

```
var allCheckboxControls = Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
```

If you only want to get the controls that are checked, then you can add a `Where` clause to that:

```
var allCheckedCheckBoxes = Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(c => c.Checked);
```

And finally, if you want to compare the `Name` property with the `Text` property (this part I'm not sure about - your question was a little unclear), then you can do something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Display a message box showing the Name and Text for each Checked CheckBox
    foreach (var checkbox in Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(c => c.Checked))
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Checkbox named {checkbox.Name}, " + 
            $"with Text {checkbox.Text}, is checked");
    }
}
```

---

I updated your sample code so it compiles, and so it better expresses what I *think* your intent is based on your comments. Please correct it if I got it wrong.

It appears you have a mapping between three things - a `Checkbox`, a `string` result from a method call, and a `string` to compare the previous string with. **And it appears that you only want to evaluate the string comparison for checkboxes that are checked**.

If this is the case, then probably the simplest thing to do given your existing code is to simply add another condition to each existing condition so it returns true if: (a checkbox is *not* checked) OR (the conditions are true). Note that **the conditions are not evaluated if the corresponding checkbox is not checked**, which is what your current code is implicitly doing.

For example:

```
while (a != 347)
{
    text1 = SomeOperation1();
    text2 = SomeOperation2();
    text3 = SomeOperation3();
    text4 = SomeOperation4();
    text5 = SomeOperation5();

    // This will only evaluate the text comparison for checkboxes that are checked
    if ((!checkBox1.Checked || text1 == "t1") &&
        (!checkBox2.Checked || text2 == "t2") &&
        (!checkBox3.Checked || text3 == "t3") &&
        (!checkBox4.Checked || text4 == "t4") &&
        (!checkBox5.Checked || text5 == "t5"))
    {
        SomeOperation6();
        a = 347;
    }
}
```

Comment: Added some code that will maybe help you understand ;)

Comment: That code you added doesn't compile and doesn't really help (at least for me it makes this more confusing). If `some operation` is a string, why do you have `some operation` on a line by itself inside the `if`? Why do you assign all 5 `textN` variables to the same value? And then why do you compare their values to different variables (`t1`, `t2`, etc)? And where are `t1`, `t2`, etc. defined? Can you please post an *actual* sample (that compiles) that describes what you want?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, forgot about "". That "some operation" is a checking some part of text in file, nothing important.  T1, t2 etc are text, forgot "" but I already wrote it, thx !

Comment: Can you please update your code so it compiles? Because you don't have "some operation" defined as a method. Should it be `SomeOperation()`? And do you mean to be assigning the result of the same `SomeOperation()` method to each string, or are they different operations (like `SomeOperation1()`, `SomeOperation2()`, etc).

Comment: @user3057699 I modified your sample code so it would compile. Please update it if I did not express your intent correctly.

Comment: I updated my answer with a response to the updated question.

Comment: Ok, thx for reply. Cant check it right now, but this IF will work correct when user select any amount of this checkboxes ?